# Indent lines as I type in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I know that `gg=G` is one of the simplest and easiest commands to indent lines in vim.

But, is there a way to indent lines as I type and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: As in, you press 'return' to go to the next line, and Vim auto-indents appropriately, based on the previous line?

Comment: @meagar: Yes. I'll edit question accordingly

Comment: Is my answer on the right track or are you asking for `gg=G` to happen every time you press enter?

Comment: @Zach: I am trying your answer. Please wait.

Comment: Yea no problem, take your time

Comment: And you can use `map ,i gg=G`  to make all indent as a shortcut

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Add the following to your vimrc:

```
set autoindent
filetype plugin indent on
```

Autoindent just indents based on the previous line's indentation if it does not know how to indent. Filetype indentation uses some things vim knows about what kind of programming language you are writing in to indent it correctly. Filetype indentation will override autoindentation.

Comment: @glts: how to autoindent a .php file?

Comment: I would like to indent as I type. The answer provided works in .c file but not in .php file

Comment: Vim doesn't indent php correctly by default, you have to install a plugin: https://github.com/StanAngeloff/php.vim